# Tweepy StreamListener "def on_status" not executing

Tags: python, tweepy

I have the following code to make a Stream Listener and get tweets from the Twitter API.

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    #class constructor
    def __init__(self,api=None):

        super(MyStreamListener,self).__init__()

        #creates class variables and instantiates to file and number
        self.num_tweets = 0
        self.file = open("tweets.txt",'w') 

    #function to collect tweets and add to file    
    def on_status (self,status):
        tweet = status._json
        print("Tweet: " + tweet)
        print("STATUS: " + status.text)
        self.file.write(json.dumps(tweet)+'\n')

        print(status)
        self.num_tweets+=1

        if self.num_tweets < 100:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        self.file.close()

l = MyStreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth,l)

stream.filter(track=[])
```

Although there are no errors with this code, the program does not print anything as is the projected output in the lines

```
print("Tweet: " + tweet)
print("STATUS: " + status.text)
```

I have tried to adjust the line

```
stream.filter(track=[])
```

to include

```
stream.filter(track=['trump','clinton'])
```

but I still did not receive any output.

Help on why this problem is occurring or a possible solution would be appreciated.

EDIT: Future debugging shows that the on_status function is not even running at any time, despite the fact that this is shown in the [tweepy docs.](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/tweepy/latest/tweepy.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem was in an incorrect access key, the error code was not printing for some reason. I solved the problem by rewriting the class and creating a new streaming application with a new key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Tweepy's StreamListener to filter tweets by just a keyword like trump or clinton, I think you're better off overriding the `on_data` method instead. You should receive the data like you're expecting then.

I'd double check this but it seems like their [docs](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html) are down?

Comment: Ok I'll try the `on_data` method.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `json.loads()` function to obtain all the data? That gives a nicer format to work from:

```
def on_status (self, status):
    all_data = json.loads(status)
    tweet = all_data['text']
    print("Tweet: " + tweet)
    print("STATUS: " + all_data + '\n')
    self.file.write(tweet) + '\n')
```

Now you have your status as a dictionary format in `all_data` that you can access to find the Tweet and all other variables.

Comment: Yes but the print() calls are not showing up in the console, and I set a breakpoint at the line `def on_status (self, status):` and the breakpoint never occurred either.